# Custom Airflow Callback Plugin Won't Work

Tags: airflow

Our codebase has many of the same Slack callback functions pasted many times, so I am hoping to move them to a separate plugin and call the functions from there. However I am having issues with the the code even being able to reach the plugin. I am hitting errors in my `try/except` block which means I am doing something wrong in the `DAG` to begin with, however I am not having much luck.

**The `DAG` Code**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.slack_airflow_plugins import SlackSuccessAlert
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime
import urllib


def slack_callback(context):
    operator = SlackSuccessAlert(
        dag_id = context.get("task_instance").dag_id,
        task_id = context.get("task_instance").task_id,
        execution_date = context.get("execution_date").isoformat()
        )

    return operator.execute(context=context)

default_args = {
    "depends_on_past": False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 5, 1)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='slack_plugin_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1
)

success_task_test = DummyOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    provide_context=True,
    on_success_callback=slack_callback,
    dag=dag)

success_task_test
```

**The Plugin Code**

```
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.operators.slack_operator import SlackAPIPostOperator
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
import urllib
import os
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin


# Slack Alerts
# HOSTNAME variable set in docker-compose
base_url = "https://"+os.getenv('HOSTNAME')
slack_channel = 'airflow-alerts-test'
slack_conn_id = 'slack'
slack_token = str(BaseHook.get_connection("slack").password)


class SlackSuccessAlert(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            dag_id,
            task_id,
            execution_date,
            emoji = ':green_check:',
            message = 'has succeeded',
            *args,
            **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dag_id = dag_id
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.execution_date = execution_date
        self.emoji = emoji
        self.message = message

    def execute(self, context):
        #dag_id = self.dag_id
        #task_id = self.task_id
        #execution_date = self.execution_date
        encoded_execution_date = urllib.parse.quote_plus(self.execution_date)
        dag_url = (f'{base_url}/graph?dag_id={self.dag_id}'
                   f'&execution_date={encoded_execution_date}')
        slack_message = (f'{self.emoji} *{self.dag_id}* <{dag_url}|*{self.message}*>.')
        slack_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
            task_id='slack_alert',
            channel=slack_channel,
            token=slack_token,
            text=slack_message
        )
        try:
            return slack_alert.execute(context=context)
        except:
            print("something going wrong with the callback...")



class SlackAlertsTest(AirflowPlugin):
    """
    Custom Slack Plugins for Airflow
    """
    name = "slack_airflow_plugins"
    operators = [SlackSuccessAlert]
```

I am likely having issues passing context incorrectly but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I don't receive any errors in `airflow`, aside from the `try/except` error that I added. So it seems my code doesn't even reach the point of being able to access the `plugin` properly.

I am attempting to pass through `dag_id` and `execution_date` in order for the Slack alerts build a proper URL and link to the DAG which has just succeeded/failed.

The error I am receiving is:

```
[2021-05-03 22:25:33,689] {taskinstance.py:1052} ERROR - Failed when executing success callback
[2021-05-03 22:25:33,689] {taskinstance.py:1053} ERROR - Argument ['task_id'] is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1050, in _run_raw_task
    task.on_success_callback(context)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/slack_plugin_test.py", line 11, in slack_callback
    operator = SlackSuccessAlert(
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 98, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/plugins/slack_airflow_plugins.py", line 30, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 94, in wrapper
    raise AirflowException(msg)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Argument ['task_id'] is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of banging my head, I was able to come up with a solution. Rather than creating a plugin using classes, I am simply moving my slack callbacks to a separate python file which just contains functions, and importing it as a module and calling the functions.
In this example, my 'plugin' being imported will be called `basicplugintest`

So, here is a sample DAG which allowed me to test 'trigger', 'success', and 'failure' callbacks. You'll notice the 'trigger' and 'success' both utilize the `on_success_callback` airflow feature, and using the `partial` library, you can customize/create case statements in the plugin to shorten the code by a few lines

The most difficult part was figuring out how `context` is used and being able to use the `partial` module to customize certain callbacks

**The DAG**

```
from airflow import DAG
import basicplugintest #this is the 'plugin' I created
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import urllib
from functools import partial

# callback_type can be specified and used with if/elif statements
# probably best to only use them for trigger/success callbacks since
# they are both considered 'on_success' callbacks
# callback_type must be ordered after context 
def trigger_success_callback(context, callback_type):
    basicplugintest.success_callback(context, callback_type)

def retry_callback(context):
    basicplugintest.retry_callback(context)

def failure_callback(context):
    basicplugintest.failure_callback(context)


default_args = {
    "depends_on_past": False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 5, 1)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='slack_plugin_test_functions',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1
)

start_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    provide_context=True,
    # specify the callback_type to correspond to case statement in the separate plugin
    on_success_callback=partial(trigger_success_callback, callback_type='started'),
    dag=dag)

success_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='success_task',
    provide_context=True,
    on_success_callback=partial(trigger_success_callback, callback_type='success'),
    dag=dag)

fail_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='fail_task',
    provide_context=True,
    bash_command='exit 123',
    retries=1,
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=10),
    on_retry_callback=retry_callback,
    on_failure_callback=failure_callback,
    dag=dag)

start_task >> success_task >> fail_task
```

And here's the plugin:

```
# added in the dags folder instead of plugins
# functions are referenced by the dags themselves
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.operators.slack_operator import SlackAPIPostOperator
import urllib
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
import os
import traceback

# Slack Alerts
# HOSTNAME variable set in docker-compose
base_url = os.getenv('AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL')
slack_channel = 'airflow-alerts-test'
slack_token = str(BaseHook.get_connection("slack").password)


def success_callback(context, callback_type):
    if callback_type == 'success':
        emoji=':green_check:'
        message='has succeeded'
        dag_id=context.get("task_instance").dag_id
        task_id=context.get("task_instance").task_id
        execution_date = context.get("execution_date").isoformat()
        encoded_execution_date = urllib.parse.quote_plus(execution_date)
        dag_url = (f'{base_url}/graph?dag_id={dag_id}'
                   f'&execution_date={encoded_execution_date}')
        run_id = context.get("task_instance").xcom_pull(key='RUN_ID', task_ids='xcom_run_id')
        slack_message = (f'{emoji} *{dag_id}* {message} for dp_run_id <{dag_url}|*{run_id}*>.')
        slack_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
            task_id='slack_alert',
            channel=slack_channel,
            token=slack_token,
            text=slack_message
        )
        return slack_alert.execute(context=context)
    
    elif callback_type == 'started':
        emoji=':airflow:'
        message='has been triggered'
        dag_id=context.get("task_instance").dag_id
        task_id=context.get("task_instance").task_id
        execution_date = context.get("execution_date").isoformat()
        encoded_execution_date = urllib.parse.quote_plus(execution_date)
        dag_url = (f'{base_url}/graph?dag_id={dag_id}'
                   f'&execution_date={encoded_execution_date}')
        run_id = context.get("task_instance").xcom_pull(key='RUN_ID', task_ids='xcom_run_id')
        slack_message = (f'{emoji} *{dag_id}* {message} for dp_run_id <{dag_url}|*{run_id}*>.')
        slack_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
            task_id='slack_alert',
            channel=slack_channel,
            token=slack_token,
            text=slack_message
        )
        return slack_alert.execute(context=context)

def retry_callback(context):
    emoji=':alert:'
    message='has missed SLA'
    dag_id=context.get("task_instance").dag_id
    task_id=context.get("task_instance").task_id
    try_number=context.get("task_instance").try_number - 1 #bug in airflow sets try_number 1 higher than it should be
    max_tries=context.get("task_instance").max_tries + 1 #max_tries is equal to number of retries set, which does not include the first attempt
    execution_date = context.get("execution_date").isoformat()
    encoded_execution_date = urllib.parse.quote_plus(execution_date)
    dag_url = (f'{base_url}/graph?dag_id={dag_id}'
               f'&execution_date={encoded_execution_date}')
    run_id = context.get("task_instance").xcom_pull(key='RUN_ID', task_ids='xcom_run_id')

    exception = context.get("exception")
    formatted_exception = ''.join(
        traceback.format_exception(etype=type(exception),
        value=exception, tb=exception.__traceback__)
    ).strip()

    slack_message = (f'{emoji} *{dag_id}* {message} for dp_run_id <{dag_url}|*{run_id}*>! Try number {try_number} out of {max_tries}. <!channel|channel>'
                f'\n*Task:* {task_id}'
                f'\n*Error:* {formatted_exception}')
    slack_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
        task_id='slack_alert',
        channel=slack_channel,
        token=slack_token,
        text=slack_message
    )

    return slack_alert.execute(context=context)


def failure_callback(context):
    emoji = ':alert:'
    message = 'has failed'
    dag_id = context.get("task_instance").dag_id
    task_id = context.get("task_instance").task_id
    execution_date = context.get("execution_date").isoformat()
    encoded_execution_date = urllib.parse.quote_plus(execution_date)
    dag_url = (f'{base_url}/graph?dag_id={dag_id}'
               f'&execution_date={encoded_execution_date}')
    run_id = context.get("task_instance").xcom_pull(key='RUN_ID', task_ids='xcom_run_id')

    exception = context.get("exception")
    formatted_exception = ''.join(
        traceback.format_exception(etype=type(exception),
        value=exception, tb=exception.__traceback__)
    ).strip()

    slack_message = (f'{emoji} *{dag_id}* {message} for dp_run_id <{dag_url}|*{run_id}*>! <!channel|channel>'
                f'\n*Task:* {task_id}'
                f'\n*Error:* {formatted_exception}')
    slack_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
        task_id='slack_alert',
        channel=slack_channel,
        token=slack_token,
        text=slack_message
    )
    return slack_alert.execute(context=context)
```